# JQuery each issue?

Tags: jquery, each

Because this html code is generated automatically by a jquery plugin (JQgrid), i cannot write the html code:

this is my html code: 
[image]

and this is the js code :

```
$("td").attr("aria-describedby","list2_estimated").each(function(){
      alert(this.text);
});
```

I want to alert the text value from `<td>`, in my case it is empty the alert. What should I do  to get the text value? thx

Comment: why is this post  voted down ? it is a relevant question

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I think the source code should be really a text, not a screenshot from a debugger/editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("td[aria-describedby = 'list2_estimated']").each(function(){
      alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: @Chester you are setting that particular attribute to all of the td elements, then why the %@$# you need this `regx` selector..? why dont you simply use `$('td')` here..?

Answer (score 0):

use **.prop()** attribute selector to get the text

```
 $("td").prop("aria-describedby","list2_estimated").each(function(){
      alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: I got the txt value from all of the td :))

Comment: @Chester All the other answers are suggesting the same.. There is nothing to do with `.prop()` over here.. I am asking the answerer that why did you use .prop() instead of .attr()..? and why did the code which use .attr() not working..?

Comment: @sudharsan This is not manishankar, this is some other unknown person

Comment: @Manishankar: please add some explanation of your solution and how it resolves the problem to help others learn in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your `td` doesnt contain any text in it, If you want to get the title of td, use like this

```
$("td[aria-describedby='list2_estimated'").each(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("title"));
});
```